# Overriding default OAuth2RestTemplate in Spring context

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, oauth-2.0

I'm using the spring spring security oAuth2 client.
And there's default OAuth2RestTemplate declaration which looks like

```
@Bean
@Primary
public OAuth2RestTemplate oauth2RestTemplate(OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext,
        OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails details) {
    OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(details,
            oauth2ClientContext);
    return template;
}
```

What I need is to provide custom error handling so i'm trying to put it into context like

```
@Bean
public OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate(OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext,     
         OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails details) {
    OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(details, oauth2Context);

    restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new DefaultResponseErrorHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
            // do some stuff
        }
    });

    return restTemplate;
}
```

The issue here is that default implementation is annotated as `@Primary` and so i'm wondering how that can be overridden?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of overriding the default implementation you probably can just get it's default instance and set all the properties that you need. See the example below.

```
@Configuration
public class OverridenConfiguration {
    @Autowire
    private OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @PostConstruct
    public void customSettings() {
        System.out.println("************** custom settings ***********");
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new DefaultResponseErrorHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
                // do some stuff
            }
        });
    }
}
```